# edit a txt file with DOS Windows command line FOR

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, for-loop, command

After using dos commands to collect data and ' findstr ' and  'for ', I now have a data file that looks like this:

```
 string9
 40%
 string1
 55%
 string12
 78%
 ...at least 9 strings more strings with their associated percentages
```

I need the data to format to this:

```
string9  40%
string1 55%
string12 78%
```

I know the FOR command is probably what I need. If i could pass a backspace to the begining of every other line, that would be nice.

Here is code that got me to this point.

```
@echo off
netsh wlan show networks mode=BSSI > rssifile.txt
findstr /V "Channel Interface There Network Authentication Encryption BSSID Radio Channel rates"       rssifile.txt >rssifil1.txt
if exist closer.txt del closer.txt /Q
if exist closer01.txt del closer01.txt /Q
if exist clos0001.txt del clos0001.txt /Q
for /F "usebackq tokens= 1,2 delims=:" %%G IN ("rssifil1.txt") DO echo %%H >>closer.txt 
more +1 closer.txt > closer01.txt
```

It is a work in progress.  Below is one possible approach I am toying with:

```
rem pseudo code for sorting and collecting RSSI %
 set nayme="nayme0"
 set /A Cnt=1
  If Cnt < 13 
 for /F "tokens" %%a in (%InFile%) do (
 echo nayme %%a >>  clos0001.txt
 if nayme="nayme0"
   nayme=nayme1
   goto far  

  if nayme="nayme1"
   nayme=nayme2
   goto far  

  if nayme="nayme1"
   nayme=nayme2
   goto far  

  if nayme="nayme1"
   nayme=nayme2
   goto far  

 :far
```

This approach, psuedo coded above involves putting the 12 RSSI names I am monitoring in sequence as well.

The file would look like this:

```
nayme0 77%
nayme1 84%
nayme2 88%    ...
```

The end result would be a one line file that would be appended to another file.

Collecting the 12 percentages in order would eliminate listing the nayme / SSID.
The line in the text file would look like this:

```
3:14 PM  57% 67% 97% 36% 47% 88% 95% 22% 85% 77% 33% 79%
```

Comment: post the code you used to get this datafile. Probably there is a way to adapt it to give you what you want instead of postprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for your initial question.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show networks mode^=BSSID ^|findstr "^SSID Signal"') do (
    echo %%i|find "SSID" >nul && (echo(!line! & set "line=%%j") || (set "line=!line!%%j" )
    )
echo %line%
```

rest tomorrow - it's quite late now here...

Questions:  Do you watch a known list or should it be dynamic? What do you do if there is a week connection to one of them and you loose it from time to time?

Comment: Sweet! I set up offices in many places. I use several methods to check the best measurements. This uses 12 previously abandoned DSL modems to broadcast. There are 3 channels I am interested in : 1, 6 and 11. I have 4 groups of three modems using the three channels. I place a group in each of 4 corners of the office and used to place an arduino where I want to locate the WiFi Access Point to get the readings. The arduino would only collect at best 600 readings before failing. I will now be able to running this all night. Almost finished! Thanks for the extremely clean answer.